# Weird behavior with accents, strings and json

Tags: json, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have JSON data with accents in it and got some unexpected results: Sometimes characters are replaced with � as in wrong encoding, but not every time.

Here are reproductions of the problem and some scenarios I tried to understand the logic

I'm using Python 3.11.0.
All my files are encoded using UTF-8.

Here are the tests I did to try to understand the logic/bug.

The problem:

```py
# Content of file1.json:
# {"a": "à"}
# Hex dump: 7B 22 61 22 3A 20 22 C3 A0 22 7D

with open("file1.json", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()

print(text) # {"a": "à"}
print(json.loads(text)) # {'a': '�\xa0'}
```

But this works

```py
# Content of file2.json:
# "à"
# Hex dump: 22 C3 A0 22

with open("file2.json", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()

print(text) # "à"
print(json.loads(text)) # à
```

I also tried opening with UTF-8 (which I believe is the default?)
and this doesn't work.

```py
with open("file2.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    text = file.read()

print(text) # "�"
print(json.loads(text)) # �
```

Then I tried just with strings and it confused me even further

```py
text = '"à"'
print(text) # "�"
print(json.loads(text)) # �
```

```py
text = '{"a": "à"}'
print(text) # {"a": "�"}
print(json.loads(text)) # {'a': '�'}
```

Comment: the `à` is represented by `\xc3\xa0` in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: We can't know which actual bytes you are looking at. Can you provide hex dumps of the input files? See also the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) and http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: @Chinez Please take care to put a useful edit comment. You fixed typos and formatting, not grammar (and misspelling the word looks bad; it would perhaps be funny if it wasn't so common).

Comment: @tripleee I edited the message. Also, thank you for the links, I learned some things about utf-8, but I still don't understand what happens in my case.

Comment: @tripleee okay, noted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found where the problem was: vs code output was not using utf-8

I don't know why the output doesn't when the terminal does, but I switched to the terminal.

Now, the results are what I expected:
Note that the encoding parameter is needed

```py
with open("file2.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    text = file.read()

print(text) # "{"a": "à"}"
print(json.loads(text)) # {'a': 'à'}
```